# How do I create multiple tables from one single API Call using django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am an FE dev that is trying to venture into the world of Python & Django.

To learn this, I am creating a sort of mock trading app. I have 2 models. `User` and `UserPortfolio`. Currently, I can create both tables independently through 2 different API Calls. However, I would love to be able to create `UserPortfolio` when `User` is created. I have established a `OneToOne` relationship between the tables.

Using python, what is the best way to achieve this efficiently? 
Extra quick question, is it good practice in Django to split models inside a project into their own files?

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Inside a folder called models, my `user.py` looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, \
                                       PermissionsMixin

from .user_portfolio import UserPortfolio                                       

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Creates and saves new user"""

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email address is required')

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Custom user model that supports using email instead of username"""

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_of_birth = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

in another file `user_portfolio.py`, I have the model and it looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class UserPortfolioManager(models.Manager):
    """User Portfolio Manager"""
    def create_user_portfolio(self, user_id, **extra_fields):

        user_portfolio = self.model(user_id=user_id, **extra_fields)
        user_portfolio.save(using=self._db)

        return user_portfolio


class UserPortfolio(models.Model):
    """User portfolio model"""

    amount_invested = models.FloatField()
    profits = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    loss = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    objects = UserPortfolioManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Created!'
```

I have a file for my serializers:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from rest_framework import serializers

from core.models import UserPortfolio

class UserPortfolioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serialzier from user portfolio object"""

    class Meta:
        model = UserPortfolio
        fields =(
            'id', 
            'amount_invested',
            'profits',
            'loss',
        )
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
        return UserPortfolio.objects.create_user_portfolio(user_id=user_id, **validated_data)

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for users object"""
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = (
            'email',
            'password',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'date_of_birth',
            'phone_number'
        )
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'min_length': 5}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create a new user with encrypted password and return it"""
        return get_user_model().objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

and my `views.py` file:

```
from rest_framework import generics, viewsets, mixins, serializers
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

from core.models import UserPortfolio

from user.serializers import UserSerializer, UserPortfolioSerializer


class CreateUserView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """Create new user in the system"""
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class CreateUserPortfolioView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserPortfolioSerializer
```

The way I currently understand it is that the `user_portfolio` table will have a `user_id` which references the user which the portfolio belongs to. 
A portfolio should be unique to a user and can only ever be owned by one user, and then a user can only have one portfolio.

Comment: You can add your logic to the serializer part here. Use one serializer for creating the instance and do the logic there.

Comment: @dipesh thank you for your response :) would you recommend to add this `UserPortfolio.objects.create_user_portfolio(user_id=user_id, **validated_data)` to the create method inside UserSerializer? or does it need to return both?

Comment: yes, I got a simple answer for you. Hope this will be helpful for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by changing the logic in one of your serializers. I will change your `UserPortfolioSerializer` into something like below.

```py
class UserPortfolioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserPortfolio
        fields =(
            'id',
            'user', 
            'amount_invested',
            'profits',
            'loss',
        )
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop(user)
        user = User.objects.create_user(**user_data)
        return UserPortfolio.objects.create_user_portfolio(user=user, **validated_data)
```

Now you need to change the input format like below:

```
{
    "user": {
            ....
            # user information here
            ....
            }
    ....
    # user portfolio information here
    ....
}
```

This is the main idea to solve your problem. I think you got the point :). By this you can do whatever change in logic inside your serializer.

Comment: Thanks so much! This answer is sweet and straight to the point and simple to understand. If it's not much to ask would you mind explaining to me how `UserPortfolioSerializer` receives the data from or is aware of `user`? @dipesh

Comment: As we are using `model serializer` in `UserPortfolioSerializer` and model for `UserPortfolioSerializer` is `UserPortfolio` which has `one to one` relation with the `User` model. Here all thing behind the scene is carried out by the `model serializer`. I hope this answer will support you :) @aromanarguello

Comment: It makes a lot of sense! I appreciate the support :)